# Creating a simple scheduler

Tags: rxjs

How would I go about creating a simple Scheduler that say, delays every item by a second? I want to use it for an Observable, and yes, I know that can be done in multiple other ways, I jsut want to accomplish it using a custom Scheduler.

There's some related tutorial here: http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2010/05/12/introduction-to-the-reactive-extensions-for-javascript-custom-schedulers/ but it is quite outdated and the API looks very different now.

The current docs are not very usefuleither, but I guess I should be using `Rx.Scheduler.prototype.schedulePeriodic`, although I don't know what the `action` parameter should be.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To create a new scheduler from the base scheduler you should have a look at [scheduler.js](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/concurrency/scheduler.js). Essentially you need to understand how to do 4 things and you will automatically get all the periodic, recursive, exception handling extensions for free.

The function signature of `Scheduler` is

```
function Scheduler(now, schedule, scheduleRelative, scheduleAbsolute){}
```

To break it down:

**now** - A function that represents the schedulers notion of time, at any point when this is called it should return what the scheduler thinks *now* is. The default is to simply return `new Date()`

**schedule** - A function called when the action should be executed as soon as possible This function has the signature

```
function scheduleNow(state, action) {}
```

where action will have the signature

```
function action(scheduler, state) {}
```

It is used to schedule immediate actions on the scheduler. Immediate will have different meanings depending on your scheduler, however, for most cases (`immediateScheduler` aside) you will want that to occur in the next `tick`, whatever that means to your scheduler. You can have a look at the [defaultScheduler](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/concurrency/defaultscheduler.js#L158), which does a little work to figure out what the best method would be in the environment (`setImmediate` is the first choice). In your case, since immediate will really mean "one second from now", you could probably just route it to `scheduleRelative` with `this.scheduleRelativeWithState(state, 1000, action)`

**scheduleRelative** This is called when the action should occur sometime in the future relative to now:

```
function scheduleRelative(state, dueTime, action) {}
```

Again this will likely use `setTimeout` with `dueTime` as the time parameter.

**scheduleAbsolute** This is probably the easiest to implement, it has the same signature as *scheduleRelative*, however instead of taking a time *relative* to now it is taking an absolute time irrespective of now (usually a `Date` object), to convert it you really just need to subtract `now` from it and pass it into `this.scheduleWithRelativeAndState` (see I told you you'll get free stuff).

In all cases the 3 schedule methods return a `Disposable`, this is used for best effort cancellation of the action. In the case of `setTimeout` this would be clearing the timeout using the returned id.

To finally answer your question, if you wanted to delay everything by 1 second the best way will probably be to apply a shift in `scheduleRelative` adding 1 second/1000 milliseconds to each scheduled event.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I am still a bit confused by the `disposable.setDisposable(action(scheduler, state));` in the `default` scheduler example. What's the purpose of this line? What's action exactly here?

Comment: This line has a couple purposes. 1) It is executing the scheduled `action`. 2) It is supporting recursive scheduling or asynchronous actions, essentially in both cases it should return a disposable that can cancel the resulting operation.  As to what `action` is, it can be any work that has been scheduled by the scheduler (usually a function wrapper around a closure passed into an operator).