# How to create own Scheduler?

Tags: rxjs

If you worked with **Schedulers** you probably know that you can use different already predefined schedulers like **queue, async or asap**:

```
of('', queueScheduler)
of('', asyncScheduler)
of('', asapScheduler)
```

that's all more or less clear.

But what if you want to **create your own scheduler**, for example: to make a 5s delay?

I could not find any examples/documations about it, except this outdate SO answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921043/274500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution that I found was to extend AsyncScheduler:

```js
class MyScheduler extends AsyncScheduler {
  public schedule<T>(
    work: (this: SchedulerAction<T>, state?: T) => void,
    delay: number = 0,
    state?: T
  ): Subscription {
    return super.schedule(work, delay + 5000, state);
  }
}

const myScheduler = new MyScheduler(AsyncAction);
console.time('myScheduler');
of(1).pipe(observeOn(myScheduler)).subscribe(v => console.timeEnd('myScheduler'));
```

sandbox - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-my-scheduler?file=index.ts

Comment: May you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67139504/order-of-execution-with-rxjs-asapscheduler